# How colored model when parsing obj file on THREE JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to color the parsed *.obj model
ObjLoader with color if load:

```
loader.load("./fox.obj", function(model) {model.traverse(function(child) {
  if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
     child.material.color = 0xffb830;
  }
```

And how added color, with parse?:

```
    const objLoader = new OBJLoader()
    var root = objLoader.parse(model.parametersData)
```

Comment: Right after `var root =...`, try to add this `root.traverse( child => { if (child.isMesh) child.material.color.set(0xffb830); } )`

Comment: After parse (not load) obj "isMesh" does not exist on type 'Object3D<Event>'.

Comment: Then try to check the way you did before with `instanceof`.